# Driving Nightwatch Tests through REPL

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

I currently have nightwatch.js setup using the vue automated setup.  That template is located here.

https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/tree/master/template/test/e2e

Is it possible to run nightwatch assertions through the command line in a REPL like fashion that is available in webdriver.io?  Here is a reference to the webdriver feature https://twitter.com/webdriverio/status/806911722682544128

---

Update, we have moved to using Cypress.io  It has made us pretty happy

Comment: i actually went with testcafe.js as nightwatch.js unfortunately does not come close to what i expect from an e2e testing tool...

Comment: @phoet we moved to webdriver.io   Still haven't found anything in the JS world that is up to same level as rails.

Comment: tried webdriver as well, found testcafe to be especially nice to integrate. worked more or less out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nightwatch-repl` package available on NPM.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nightwatch-repl

```
// nightwatch.conf.js

var repl = require('nightwatch-repl');

module.exports = (function (settings) {
    repl.init(settings);
    ...
    ...
    return settings;
})(require('./nightwatch.json'));
```

Once you run your tests and invoke browser.repl()

you should see the following in your console

```
Running:  Login to dashboard

Type in a command (eg: browser.function()) or type "quit" to exit
repl>
```